# Azure Mobile Service After PurgeAsync It add UpdateAt Filter to next PullAsync Call

Tags: azure, windows-mobile, azure-mobile-services

I am Using Azure Mobile Service Offline Sync with Windows Phone.
First time I am adding data to local database(sqlite) Filtered by userId.
Then for second user I am using PurgeAsync for all tables just to clear first user data and load second user data.
But, For second user request goes with filter with updatedat value.
Which is the timestamp of purge operation performed.
Which make no data download for second user.

Comment: I have the same problem.  Any resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by passing null value for queryid.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should supply a different string in the PullAsync method for each user and it will work properly.